# Strategy for finding optimal bagging parameters

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, bootstrap, scikit-learn, bagging

I am using a BaggingClassifier of SVMs in sklearn. What is the best strategy for finding optimal parameters, using my training/vaildation data?

When using the full dataset, I can use grid search to find the best SVM params. However, I presume that these params will change, depending on the number of estimators and max_samples used in bagging?

Here is my code:

```
svm = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', probability=True, C=4, gamma=0.001, class_weight='balanced'))
n_estimators = 30
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(BaggingClassifier(svm, max_samples=0.3, n_estimators=n_estimators, bootstrap=True, n_jobs=5))
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
clf.predict(x_valid)
```

Is it generally best to just use the highest bagging settings feasible (in terms of computation time)? e.g: 200 estimators and 1.0 max_samples?

Comment: Generally, more estimators usually has a better performance in terms of variance, but its training time grows linearly. Ensemble methods (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html) gives you some suggestions on how to tune the parameters.